# Java - Is it possible for n threads to be assigned randomly to m threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, thread-safety

I'm trying to create a program in Java where each student is a thread, that completes an assignment and then notifies() its assigned teacher (also a thread that wait()) to grade it and then continue to the next assignment. I want for the threads in Thread Class Students to randomly get assigned to threads from the Thread Class Teachers for the whole operation. e.g.
`numberOfStudens = 5`
`numberOfTeachers = 2`
`numberOfAssignments = 2`

Keep working together for `numberOfAssignments`

- studentThread0 - teacherThread0
- studentThread1 - teacherThread0
- studentThread3 - teacherThread0
- studentThread2 - teacherThread1
- studentThread4 - teacherThread1

So far I have created the 2 Threads and I can only achieve that by using a contractor on the teacher thread, which is not random.

**Student Thread**

```
public static class Student extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Student " + studentId + " is working on assignment " + assignmentId);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Student " + studentId + " is done with assignment " + assignmentId);
            synchronized (teacher) {
                teacher.notify();
                System.out.println("Student " + studentId + " notified teacher " + teacherId + " that assignment " + assignmentId + " is complete.");
            }
        }
}
```

**Teacher Thread**

```
 public static class Teacher extends Thread {
    public Teacher(int teacherId, int assignmentId, int studentId) {
            this.teacherId = teacherId;
            this.assignmentId = assignmentId;
            this.studentId = studentId;
        }
         public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Teacher " + teacherId + " is waiting for students to finish assignment " + assignmentId);
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Teacher " + teacherId + " is grading the " + assignmentId);
                System.out.println("Teacher " + teacherId + " is done grading the " + assignmentId + " and the grade is " + grade);
            }
            //Randomly generate a grade for the assignment
            Random random = new Random();
            grade = random.nextInt(10);
        }
 }
```

**Assignment Thread** (I'm not sure if I should keep this as a thread)

```
public static class Assignment extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
                students[i] = new Student(i, this);
                students[i].start();
            }

            teacher.start();

            System.out.println("Assignment " + assignmentId + " is complete.");
        }
}
```

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Seems like what you're looking for is a classic producer-consumer pattern - you can find many examples online, for example: https://www.baeldung.com/java-producer-consumer-problem

Comment: @YonatanKarp-Rudin I'll look further into it and maybe I can find the aswer I'm looking for. Thanks for posting.